# Location path nginx cannot serve static file vueJS

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have 2 docker containers that contain 2 websites, a new website and an old website.

New website run on port 8000 (Laravel) and the old website run on port 8001 (VueJS).

I want the location / proxy pass to the new website and the location /old proxy pass to the old website.

For new website, it can be accessed properly.

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_pass              http://localhost:8000;
}
```

but for the old website, assets, images, fonts are still 404.

```
location /old {
  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_pass              http://localhost:8001;
}
```

404 because when access https://my.domain.net/old/, the asset that should be called is https://my.domain.net/old/asset/images/logo.png

But this is still https://my.domain.net/asset/images/logo.png so that 404 is not found.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~* '^/(assets|images|fonts)/' {
  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_pass              http://localhost:8001;
}
```

> I inspect element, for location /old the assets redirect to my.domain.net/asset.css. (absolutely 404 not found)

It looks like your localhost:8001 redirects.

Comment: Assets, font, and etc still https://my.domain.net/asset/images/logo.png and still 404 not found. :( please help

Comment: wait. so you want https://my.domain.net/asset/images/logo.png to get  http://localhost:8001/asset/images/logo.png ?

Comment: When I access  https://my.domain.net/old/ , cannot load asset (404), because the assets points to https://my.domain.net/asset/images/logo.png.. should be points to https://my.domain.net/old/asset/images/logo.png

Comment: Yes. Please help me.

Comment: You are confusing me. Can you list all routes you want?

Comment: I also update my answer. It's route `my.domain.net/assets/images/logo.png to get localhost:8001/assets/images/logo.png`

Comment: I have 2 website and running on docker port 8000 and 8001. It works for location /, but for location /old without all assets. I inspect element, for location /old the assets redirect to http://my.domain.net/asset.css. (absolutely 404 not found), where it should be http://my.domain.net/old/asset.css.

Comment: And how if i have another website, example location http://my.domain.net/new. how to avoid conflicts because every website has a different asset ?

Comment: I mean list your all routes. Literally. Something like example.com/assets/a.png -> localhost:8001/assets/a.png